# Как исправить комментарий наставника?

Tags: javascript

Получил от наставника такие замечания по коду. Но если я пытаюсь ввести переменные  , то скрипт перестает работать. Как тут правильно объявить их

```js
const makeImage = (text, imageLink) => { 
    const cardElement = cardElementTemplate.cloneNode(true); 
    cardElement.querySelector('.element-grid__photo').src = imageLink; 
    cardElement.querySelector('.element-grid__text').textContent = text; 

    cardElement.querySelector('.element-grid__photo').setAttribute('alt', text); 
 /*Каждый html элемент ищется один раз (используйте переменные).
 - Повторный поиск .element-grid__photo*/

 
    cardElement.querySelector('.element-grid__like-button').addEventListener('click', toggleLikeButton); 
    cardElement.querySelector('.element-grid__delete-button').addEventListener('click', deleteImage); 

    cardElement.querySelector('.element-grid__photo').addEventListener('click', showCard); 
 
 /*Каждый html элемент ищется один раз (используйте переменные).
 - Повторный поиск .element-grid__photo*/

 
    return cardElement; 
}
```

Comment: с какой переменной ошибка?

Comment: Если я пытаюсь  cardElement.querySelector('.element-grid__photo')    сделать   переменной , то скрипт перестает работать

Comment: И покажите код с вашими изменениями, выводящий ошибку

Comment: let abc = cardElemet.querySelector('.element-grid__photo'); 
abc.addEventListener('click', showCard);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так не работает?

```js
const makeImage = (text, imageLink) => {
  const cardElement = cardElementTemplate.cloneNode(true);
  const cardElementPhoto = cardElement.querySelector('.element-grid__photo');
  const cardElementText = cardElement.querySelector('.element-grid__text');
  const cardElementLikeBtn = cardElement.querySelector('.element-grid__like-button');
  const cardElementDeleteBtn = cardElement.querySelector('.element-grid__delete-button');

  cardElementPhoto.src = imageLink;
  cardElementText.textContent = text;

  cardElementPhoto.setAttribute('alt', text);
  cardElementLikeBtn.addEventListener('click', toggleLikeButton);
  cardElementDeleteBtn.addEventListener('click', deleteImage);

  cardElementPhoto.addEventListener('click', showCard);

  return cardElement;
}
```

Comment: @Иваниванов я сделал все `querySelector` переменными, можете посмотреть, думаю поймёте логику

Comment: да , так работает , спасибо

Comment: @Иваниванов А если убрать слово "Element", функция сократится процентов на 30 )